# Removing the shadow from a button

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, shadow

The button I want is the one at bottom, but the one I have is the top.

[image]

The problem arises from the fact that the top button in HTML:

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/"><input type="submit" value="Ok" /></form>
```

and the bottom button in HTML:

```
<button type="button">Ok</button>
```

The CSS for the top button is:

```
.signup-success input[type="submit"],
.signup-success input[type="submit"]:active,
.signup-success input[type="submit"]:focus {
  width: 80%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #00AA66;
  border-color: #00AA66;
}
```

The CSS for the bottom button is:

```
.signup-success button,
.signup-success button:active,
.signup-success button:focus {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 80%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #00AA66;
  border-color: #00AA66;
}
```

If it helps the top button is generated from rails .erb extension

```
<%= button_to "Ok", root_path, :method => :get %>
```

Help me to get my top button look like bottom button. I've tried to put in code that disable shadows in CSS, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Try putting a border: none; first, and then setting your border after  it.
border:none;
border: 2px solid #00aa66;

Comment: Try setting the border-width property.... Play with different values.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use border-style:

```
.signup-success input[type="submit"],
.signup-success input[type="submit"]:active,
.signup-success input[type="submit"]:focus {
  width: 80%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #00AA66;
  border-color: #00AA66;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

or combined version (border-style, border-width and border-color in one):

```
border: 2px solid #00AA66;
```

Comment: with a little bit of border-radius and height fiddling, I got the exact shape I wanted. Thanks! and lol easy solution, guess I was impatient since I've been coding for a long time.

Comment: complete brain lapse today, thank god for this simple answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Trying to figure this minor issue out for a few days now.

Comment: border-style: solid; is what did it for me

Answer (score 10):

Or you can simply give `border: none` to your button

Answer (score 7):

Just add a border of your own.

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Or remove the border.

```
border: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Funny enough adding a border to the button fixed safari's weird drop shadow.

```html
border: 1px solid #34c1e5;
```